# Laravel collections iteration with foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, collections, foreach

[image: order model]
[image: product model]

its a simple query in a controller using Order model:

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();
return dd($orders);
```

dd gives following results: (which is correct)

```
Collection {#269 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Order {#270 ▼
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:9 [▶]
      #original: array:9 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    1 => Order {#271 ▼
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:9 [▶]
      #original: array:9 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
}
```

but when i iterate through the $orders collection foreach loop, only the first array is is shown, the second array is not accessible... whats wrong with foreach loop... ?

```
$temp='';
        foreach($orders as $order){
                $temp.= $order->product; // accessing the belongTo method
        }

        dd($temp);
```

here is the output (only one array is shown):

```
"{"id":13,"created_at":"2018-06-06 15:28:21","updated_at":"2018-06-06 18:36:28","type":0,"title":"product 3","description":"this is product no 3 with 5 images","images":"night-product-watch-dramatic-84475_1528310188.jpeg,night-product-watch-dramatic-84475_1528310188.jpeg","alive":1,"user_id":1,"deleted_at":null} ◀"
```

Comment: Show you model definition.

Comment: `class Product extends Model
{
    
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    
    
    
    Protected $fillable= ['title', 'type', 'description','images','alive'];


    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
} `

Comment: `class Order extends Model
{


    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



    Protected $fillable= ['comments', 'product_id', 'type', 'user_id', 'alive', 'granted'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}`

Comment: can you var_dump($order) so you see what is the output of the second order? Inside foreach I mean

Comment: Foreach is correct it's just you tripping I think X)

Comment: @GaimZz `return var_dump($orders);` or `return var_dump($orders->all());` both return 2 items... so yes there is something wrong with foreach loop...

Comment: $order, var dump each order inside the foreach!

Comment: @GaimZz inside the foreach loop var_dum($order) echoes both items... but this still does not solve my problem as im unable to access the associated product of order in second iteration (in first iteration it works fine)...

Comment: then that looks like your second item doesn't have a relation with products on a database level?

Comment: Can you show the relation between Order and Products on your Order Model?

Comment: i have added the order and product model images to the question...

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old thread. But I am having exactly the same issue.
My controller return the expected number of item in the collection.
Then in the foreach loop in the blade, I call a method on each item. Only the first provide the right result and the rest are null.
Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an array of products across all orders you cannot use string concatenation. Use an array and push items onto it.

```
$products = [];
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if ($order->product) {
        $products[] = $order->product;
    }
}
dd($products); // will be an array of all other products.
```

Comment: thanks, but this still does gives the second array item as null... here is the output of dd... `array:2 [▼
  0 => Product {#276 ▶}
  1 => null
]`  i just wonder whats wrong with foreach loop... or am i missing something here...

Comment: The ```null``` item for the second item means the ```Product``` is not defined. I updated the code to avoid that

Comment: this is not the issue... i am also getting the same results see `dd($temp);` in question. foreach loop suppose to loop through exactly 2 products. and currently i don't know why it loops through the first one successfully but for the second iteration it gives null... (both products exists) i think its something to do with laravel collections... may be im not properly iterating through the collection...

Comment: no change in code... upto this point the code in my question and your answer both gives the same result... but both miss the second item in collection... which is the real question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$temp= [];
foreach($orders->all() as $order){
     $temp[] = $order->product;
}
```

And you may edit your query

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                    ->with('products')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: the $temp[] code gives no output just blank screen, while if i use with('products') in query it gives error: Call to undefined relationship [products] on model [App\Order].  (relationship is defined in order as it belongs to many products, while in product it has many orders)...

Comment: `$orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();


        $temp=[];
        foreach($orders as $order){
                $temp[]= $order->product; 
        }
    
        dd($temp);`  gives following the same output, only first item is shown, and null is shown for second item...  `array:2 [▼
  0 => Product {#276 ▶}
  1 => null
]`